# Primary Key Error while inserting record into table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am passing datatable as input parameter to a stored procedure. I have created custom type for it.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_AddEmployee]
      @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
      @Code int
AS
BEGIN    
      INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], [Lname], [Code])
         SELECT 
             [Name], [Lname], @Code 
         FROM @tblEmp
```

Here it fetch record from datatable and insert into `Employee` table.

Table `Employee` has primary key (combination `Name` and `Lname`).

Table `Employee`:

```
Nmae   LName Code
Rashmi Hirve 89
Rani   Mohite 7
```

DataTable :

```
Nmae   LName
Rani   Mohite
Swati  More
Reshma Gawade
```

Problem appears when I try to add record `(Rani, Mohite)` from datatable to table `Employee`.

It causes a primary key error at first record and does not proceed further.

I want like this if error come skip that record fetch next record and insert that. There are 8000 records, which I want to pass from datatable to `Employee` table.

If I checked not exist, then insert will take long time to execute query.How to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a check for `EXISTS` on the `INSERT` statement should not have a significant effect on performance.

```
INSERT INTO Employee ([Name] ,[Lname] ,[Code])
SELECT  [Name] ,[Lname] ,@Code 
FROM    @tblEmp AS t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Employee AS e
            WHERE   e.Name = t.Name
            AND     e.Lname = t.Lname
        );
```

This is *fairly* safe, but still vulnerable to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). I think the safest way to do the insert, with is to use `MERGE` with the locking hint `HOLDLOCK`:

```
MERGE Employee WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING @tbl AS s
    ON s.Name = t.Name
    AND s.LName = t.LName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([Name] ,[Lname] ,[Code])
    VALUES (s.Name, s.Lname, @Code);
```

Comment: It worked.But I did not get why u wrote 1.Can u pls explain the code?SELECT  1
            FROM    Employee AS e
            WHERE   e.Name = t.Name
            AND

Comment: I think the [documentation on `EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188336.aspx) may do a better job of explaining than I can, but in essence it ensures that you only select rows from `@tblEmp` that do not already exist in `Employee`. `SELECT 1` is just my preference, you could use `SELECT NULL`, or `SELECT *`, or `SELECT Name`, it really does not matter, it is optimised away. I just think `SELECT 1`, and `SELECT NULL` better show the intent that nothing relevant is being selected , and `SELECT 1` is the shorter of the two to type.

Answer (score 0):

If the table has a primary key that is not set to auto generate then it will error when you try to insert a record without the key. You will need to either set the primary key field as an identity seed or you can include the primary key with the insert.